# ¿Cómo interpretar una ruta con caracteres comodines en C#?

Tags: c#

Mi cuestión es cómo tratar de interpretar un String para poder usarlo en la clase File como una ruta, pero con caracteres comodines de la misma manera que en Bash puedo realizar esto:

`rm -rf /tmp/*/folder1/*`

Quiero saber cómo implementar una manera cómoda para poder hacerlo. He visto de que tengo que utilizar Regex para ello, pero aún no me quedo claro como usarlo.

Lo quiero utilizar de esta manera:

```
string path = "/tmp/*/folder1/*";
File.Delete (path);
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: no entenderia que tienen que ver las regex aca... o por lo menos no explicaste para que queres usarlas. file.delete no acepta comodines, vas a tener que recorrer todos los archivos a mano y borrarlos.. o borrar las carpetas y volver  a crearlas.

Comment: `string path1 = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";` Para borrar debes pasar el archivo a borrar creo

Comment: igual esa ruta con esos caracteres no tiene ningun problema. ninguno de esos es un caracter especial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No requieres regex para usar una string con caracteres especiales, solo necesitas agregar el caracter @ para generar una verbatim string la cual no requiere secuencia de escape

```
string path = @"/tmp/*/folder1/*";
```

En el caso de `File.Delete(string ruta);` debes pasar el nombre del archivo a borrar con su respectivo path por lo que los comodines no te serán utilices en este caso, vas a requerir hacer uso de:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(string ruta, string patronBusqueda, SearchOption opcionDeBusqueda)
```

Para recorrer de forma recursiva los directorios en la ruta especificada y extraer los archivos con su ruta que te interesen.

De acuerdo al comentario del OP: para borrar archivos de esa ruta:

```
string path = @"..//tmp/"; //Directorio a recorrer requiere path completo ej: @"C:\tmp"
string carpeta = @"folder1"; //Nombre de carpeta a buscar recursivamente en todos los directorios de la ruta original

foreach (var directorio in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, carpeta, SearchOption.AllDirectories)) //Enumeramos los directorios que coinciden con folder1
        {
            foreach (var archivo in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directorio, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) //Obtenemos los paths + nombre de archivo que se encuentren en el directorio
            {
                 File.Delete(archivo); //Borramos el archivo
            }
        }
```

> El patron de busqueda en `EnumerateFiles` `*.*` da como resultado todos
>   los archivos con cualquier extension dentro de la carpeta, asi que acabra borrando todo archivo en la carpeta folder1 aqui puedes jugar con patrones como en bash para hacer un filtro selectivo de los arhivos que deseas eliminar

**Todos las carpetas llamdas folder1 dentro de la ruta raiz dada seran encontradas y sus archivos eliminados dependiendo del patron establecido en `EnumerateFiles`**

[Aqui esta la documentación de como funciona File.Delete(string path)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.90).aspx)

Saludos

Comment: Por la parte de como interpretar una string si, lo del caso del File.Delete actualize la respuesta para reflejarlo

Comment: Lo cual es correcto modifico la respuesta para reflejarlo

Comment: La respuesta cada vez me gusta mas.. pero seguimos sin saber, si es lo que estaba preguntando ;)

Comment: Esperare un poco para ver si amplia la pregunta antes de ampliar mas la respuesta

Comment: Ehhh, no.
Me fije lo que me respondieron y aún no logro conseguir eliminar archivos de esas rutas. D:

Comment: @Andy-devnix podras explicar mejor el problema en la pregunta? file.delete no acepta asteriscos, tenes que declarar archivo por archivo

Comment: Disculpá por no haberte respondido antes @gbianchi. Bueno no sabía lo que el método Delete de la clase File no aceptaba tales caracteres, por eso pregunté algún otro método.

Comment: Gracias @JesusRodríguez probé tu solución y me funciona, ahora trataré de jugar un poco con ese método para directorios tales como:
string path = "/path/con/varios/subdirectorios/*/*/*/*"